# Create Barcode jpg with RGhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create barcode jpg file by rghost on RoR.

When I render the RGhost barcode content, I got the exception below...

```
failed created_jpg_new: private method `readlines' called for nil:NilClass
image file is an unrecognised format
```

My coding starts `create_jpg(code_word)`

```
def create_jpg(code_word)
  begin
    img = encode(code_word)
  rescue => exc
          Rails.logger.info("failed create_jpg: #{exc}")
     else
           File.open(img_path, "w+b") { |f|
                 f << img
          }
    end
end

def encode(code_word)
    doc = RGhost::Document.new
    doc.barcode_rationalizedCodabar code_word
    return doc.render_stream(:jpg)
end
```

What's wrong on `doc.render_stream(:jpg)` or other?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?